# Strip_tags doesn't work in get_the_content

Tags: php, wordpress, strip-tags

I'm trying to make a wordpress plugin but not working and do not know what can be. The plugin should take posts by `get_the_content` but with formatting.

```
<?php
register_activation_hook('__FILE__', 'texto');
add_filter ('the_content', 'texto');
   function texto ($text){
      $text = get_the_content( '' );
      $text = apply_filters( 'the_content', $text );
     $text = strip_tags( $text, '<p></br>' );
     return  $text;
    };

?>
```

This is not working. With `$text = apply_filters ('the_content', $ text);` the blog does not load, if I take `$text = apply_filters ('the_content', $ text);` posts have no formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the single quotes around `__FILE__` to fix the problem. The filename is in your case not resolved correctly.

See this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook